# How can we toggle GPIO while booting up my system

Tags: embedded-linux, bootloader

while working on my board I want to get to know the status of the bootup. I tried to look into many articles but didn't get any conclusion on how to toggle the GPIO led while booting up and detect the bootup status just like green led blinks on the Raspberry-pi. I  too want to do the same for my board any references will be helpful.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: "*How can we toggle GPIO ...*" -- Well, you would have to use software, i.e. your boot program(s).  What boot program(s) does your board use?

Comment: No, no such program as I am using Custom board and build Yocto Bsp image to boot I am working on showing the status while booting up and after successful bootup...

Comment: tried referring to this and created the service but that service is starting just before logging in: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html I want to detect the status of the bootup and toggle GPIO till it doesn't completely boot up any suggestion will be highly helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working fine and I am able to execute it as per the requirement we need to create the service at the location

```
/lib/systemd/system/
```

being a root user we can create the service and

```
 [Unit]
 Description = Blink my LED
 DefaultDependencies=no

 [Service]
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /<your location>/boot_status.py
 
 [Install]
 WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

can refer link for more details :

```
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html
```